# Getting data from security token in rest controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am working with Spring MVC and Spring Security for rest controllers, also I am using JWT. In some cases, I need to get a username from the token to provide it as a function parameter.

Now I am solving this problem by setting username as a request attribute in the security filter.
Can you advise me on a better way to do this?

Rest controller:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/user", produces = "application/json")
    public String getUserFromToken(@RequestAttribute(name = "username") String username) throws JsonProcessingException {
        List<Data> dataSet = userService.doSomeProcessing(username);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dataSet);
    }
```

Security filter:

```
@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
                request.setAttribute("username", jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken));
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about principal
https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security

There you will find a solution to this Spring Security problem, you yourself met with a similar one, thanks for the question and good luck